# Which: ListView.setOnItemClickListener or TextView.setOnClickListener?

Tags: android, adapter, onclicklistener

I have a `ListView` with a custom adapter that only has a `TextView`, and I want to set a click listener for it.

Which one I should choose: `ListView.setOnItemClickListener` outside of the custom adapter, or `TextView.setOnClickListener` inside the custom adapter's `getView()`? And why?

Thanks!

L.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely use `ListView.setOnItemClickListener`

1. Because when you press the list item it gives feedback that you pressed it (like glow background or something)
2. You are controlling your data from outside of your list, and therefore you have better vision on the objects you are controlling
3. More object oriented
4. In my opinion it's easier
5. If you have only one view in a list row then why bother setting the click listener on the TextView instead of the row?

Comment: Perfect! Hence, implicitly, I understand that I should only use `TextView.setOnClickListener` if I have several views in a row. Correct?

Comment: Correct. Therefore you set a listener for every view you want to listen click for.

Answer (score 1):

adding onClickListener to views in the getView() method is using when you have 2 or more views that should have their own onClickListener,so for your is better onItemClickListener