# Android:Error on setOnClickListerner while trying to handle click event

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a ListView and I am trying to handle the click event on list of items via the following code

```
listView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

               // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
```

But I am getting compile time error which is as following

```
   The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){})
```

How can this error be resolved ?

Comment: You have choose wrong listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setOnItemClickListener()` to set a listener for item clicks. `setOnClickListener()` would register a regular `View.OnClickListener` on the `ListView` widget itself.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `setOnClickListener` by `setOnItemClickListener` :-)

Comment: @AnkitGarg Glad it helped, Ankit! Please mark any of the answers as a correct answer, to resolve this question.

Answer (score 1):

use `setOnItemClickListener()`

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             String item = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `setOnItemClickListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`

> adding onClickListener to views in the getView() method is using when
>   you have 2 or more views that should have their own onClickListener,so
>   for your is better onItemClickListener

i.e. rewrite your code as

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

               // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
```

For more info see
[Which: ListView.setOnItemClickListener or TextView.setOnClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446195/which-listview-setonitemclicklistener-or-textview-setonclicklistener)